# Does training time increase more if I add a layer at the beginning of a neural network or at the end?

Tags: neural-networks, backpropagation, train, time-complexity

Let's consider a fixed NN architecture, dataset and hardware. We add a layer, either at the beginning or at the end of the NN. In which case the training time will increase more? Intuitively, I imagine the answer may depend on a few factors:

- whether the NN is a autoencoder (input has same dimension as output), an encoder (input is way higher-dimensional than output), etc.
- which type of layer I'm adding: for the sake of argument, let's limit ourselves to very common layers, such as Conv, Dense, GCNConv or Self-Attention

Thus, I'm looking for an answer that considers at least two cases (say, autoencoder and encoder), but clearly explains the logic behind the answer, so that I can adapt it to other cases. Ideally, the answer would consider the time complexity of training a neural network by backpropagation.

Comment: Hmm... (+1) But it feels quite broad. In general, adding layers at the beginning might be more beneficial for tasks requiring feature extraction and representation learning while adding layers at the end might be more effective for tasks like regression and classification. So this might also affect, how much effort (i.e. training time) they require to fine-tune. That said, backpropagation will also certainly be affected more. by layers towards the end of the network as they will have the most downstream impact (by definition).

Comment: @usεr11852 ok. I think you could articulate an answer on two levels: to first order (or let's say, without having any info on the learning task), adding a layer at the end of the network will impact training time more because bla bla bla (maybe a couple equation or even a simple example would make for a better answer). To a second order, if we know which is the learning task, then the effect on the training time may be different because etc. etc. etc.

Comment: There's more parameters to fit with an extra layer, but if the larger model contains a better possibility for a good fit, then I imagine that *training time can also decrease*. Basically the question boils down to how well the model represents the truth, and whether it's architecture is 'smart' enough to allow easy paths to converge to a close fit with that truth. Training time depends not only on the complexity and numbers of parameters to fit, and it is also depending on convergence rate. Badly designed models can take a long time to fit, if they ever reach a good enough fit.

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus your point doesn't have any relevance to the question. I'm considering the effect of adding a layer to an existing model. I don't care if there are other better designed models. I want to estimate the variation in time complexity when we add a layer to a given model.

Comment: *"Training time depends not only on the complexity and numbers of parameters to fit, and **it is also depending on convergence rate. Badly designed models can take a long time to fit**"* What this means is that the question of adding an extra layer is not just whether it means more parameters to fit but *also* whether it makes the model 'better' and more suitable to converge well. Certain types of layers can be an improvement in this sense, they can help the model to fit *faster*. An example would be a convolutional layer at the start that makes a model more adaptable to translations.

Comment: An analogous example is solving partial differential equations with a finite element method that describes a certain space on a grid or a mesh (like in fluid dynamics problems). Increasing the number of elements in the mesh means generally that the computations become larger (more parameters to solve), but in some cases it can make it easier for the model to converge to a solution (for example corners and high gradients in the solution can require a finer mesh to allow the model to convergence). For neural networks this is similar. Models can sometimes fit faster with more parameters.